# Perl DBI execute with an array instead of list of scalars

Tags: perl, dbi

I build a query depending on certain conditions - such as type of operation, or the presence of a certain value - by adding fields to a `INSERT` statement. But then I have to branch for different DBI `execute`s with different lists of parameters, like this:

```
if ($x) {$extraFields .= ' , X'; $extraValues= ',? '}
if ($y) {$extraFields .= ' , Y, Z'; $extraValues= ',?, ? '}

my $theBasicQuery = "INSERT INTO sometable (A, B, $extraFields) VALUES (?, ? $extraValues)";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($theBasicQuery) or error

# but I dont want to have to do this if for execute
if ($x) {$sth->execute(1,2,99);}
if ($y) {$sth->execute(1,2,88, 77);}
```

I would prefer to do something like this:

```
{$sth->execute($anArrayWithDifferentParams);}
```

Is this possible? Or is there another way to do something similar?

Comment: Why not store the field names in an array, and then `join` the array when you form your query string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To more directly answer the question, the way to execute a query with an array instead of a list of scalars is simply to pass it an array.  `$sth->execute(@params)` will work just fine.

```
if ($x) {$extraFields .= ' , X'; $extraValues = ',? '; @params = (99); }
if ($y) {$extraFields .= ' , Y, Z'; $extraValues = ',?, ? '; @params = (88, 77); }

my $theBasicQuery = "INSERT INTO sometable (A, B, $extraFields) VALUES (?, ? $extraValues)";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($theBasicQuery) or error

$sth->execute(1,2, @params);
```

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend using a SQL building tool to help you with this. My favorite is to [SQL::Interp](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL%3a%3aInterp), used in combination with [DBIx::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aSimple). Such a tool will manage your bind variables for you, and DBIx::Simple also handles preparing and re-using the statement handles for you automatically. A solution with DBIx::Simple/SQL::Interp would look like this:

```
$db->iquery("INSERT INTO sometable", {
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
    %extra
});
```

SQL::Abstract is also popular and have a solution with a similar syntax.

Comment: Thanks! they do look pretty cool. One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm not allowed / is not possible to install new CPAN modules. Will try it out still.

Comment: Strange. You mean, the administrator won't allow new *global* installation of Perl modules, or that you aren't allowed to add them locally, either? What if you copy a file from CPAN, paste it into your tree, and name it My::SQL::Interp?

Answer (score 2):

**One approach:**

```
my %insert = ( A => 1, B=> 2 );

if ($condition_x) {
  $insert{X} = 99;
}

if ($condition_y) {
  $insert{Y} = 88;
  $insert{Z} = 77;
}

# 1. sprintf isn't very perlish, but I find it clearer here
# 2. quote_identifier():  you won't ever need this until you need it very badly
#
my $query = sprintf('INSERT INTO tbl (%s) VALUES (%s)',
                       join ', ' => map { $dbh->quote_identifier($_) } keys %insert,
                       join ', ' => ('?') x keys %insert);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);  # Perhaps prepare_cached, instead?
$sth->execute(values %insert);
```

**Caveat:  !DIY**

If at all possible, don't do it yourself!  Use a module, as suggested elsewhere.  Others have already solved this problem, more cogently and reliably than the above.

Answer (score 0):

You might find my [DBIx::PreQL](http://search.cpan.org/?module=DBIx%3a%3aPreQL) library helpful for this kind of task.  It provides a way to mark up an SQL query for processing based on available data.

DBIx::PreQL uses simple prefixes and named placeholders to label which lines of a query should be included.

For example, `*` means 'always include' and `&` means 'include if all data fields for the line are present.

Your query would be marked up as follows:

```
*  INSERT INTO sometable (
*     A
*    ,B
&    ,C !C!  
&    ,D  !D!
)
*VALUES (
*   ?A?
*  ,?B?
&  ,?C?
&  ,?D?
* )
```

And you'd pass the query and a data hash like `{ A => '123', B => 'foo', D => 'bar' }` to the query processor, which would return the query:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (
     A
    ,B
    ,D
)
VALUES (
   ?
  ,?
  ,?
 )
```

And the parameter list `(123, 'foo', 'bar')`.